# How to unit test angular method having HTMLInputElement as parameter?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

Below is my code snippet

code

```
applyFilter(event: Event): void {
        const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
        this.filterBy = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
        this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
    }
```

Test cases

```
 fit('applyFilter', () => {
        const event = new Event('click');
        component.applyFilter(event);
    });
```

Error i am getting is "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null"
while this conversion "(event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;" meentioned error is occuring

Answer (score 4):

I would just mock the object.

```
it('should change filterBy and dataSource.filter', () => {
  const event = { target: { value: 'hello' } } as any;
  component.applyFilter(event);
  expect(component.filterBy).toBe('hello');
  expect(component.dataSource.filter).toBe('hello');
});
```